# Как изменить состояние всех элементов checkBox и radioButton?

Tags: c#, winforms

Как изменить состояние всех элементов checkBox и radioButton на форме Windows Form? Может есть какая-нибудь функция отдельная для этого? Приведу кусок кода как это делаю я:

```
void Reset(bool flag)
        {
            radioButton1.Checked = flag;
            radioButton2.Checked = flag;
            radioButton3.Checked = flag;
            radioButton4.Checked = flag;
            radioButton5.Checked = flag;
            radioButton6.Checked = flag;
            radioButton7.Checked = flag;
        }
```

Comment: А что именно нужно? какая у тебя задача?

Comment: мне просто нужно их обнулить при нажатии кнопки, а этих элементов около 30 штук

Comment: Можно циклом foreach поискать в списке Controls элементы типа RadioButton или CheckBox, после чего заменить им свойство Checked на нужное.

Comment: Не удалось привести тип объекта "System.Windows.Forms.Panel" к типу "System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton".

Comment: `foreach(RadioButton radioButton in Controls)
            {
                radioButton.Checked = flag;
            }`

Comment: `foreach(RadioButton radioButton in Controls.OfType<RadioButton>()){...}`

Comment: или оно не работает, или я очень туп)

Comment: можно руками, а можно сделать биндинг к модели и забыть про ручные манипуляции.